# longest contiguous subsequence such that twice the number of zeroes is less than equal to thrice the number of ones

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem from hacker rank I tried the brute fore solution but it doesnt seem to work. Can some one gimme an idea to solve this problem efficiently.
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/sep13/challenges/sherlock-puzzle

Given a binary string (S) which contains ‘0’s and ‘1’s and an integer K, 
find the length (L) of the longest contiguous subsequence of (S * K) such that twice the number of zeroes is <= thrice the number of ones (2 * #0s <= 3 * #1s) in that sequence.

S * K is defined as follows: S * 1 = S
S * K = S + S * (K - 1)

Input Format 
The first (and only) line contains an integer K and the binary string S separated by a single space.

Constraints
1 <= |S| <= 1,000,000
1 <= K <= 1,000,000

Output Format
A single integer L - the answer to the test case

Comment: Please show your "brute force solution", else it appears we are doing all the work for you.

Comment: hi. Im not looking for code. All i need is just an idea for solving this problem. There are hundreds of solutions available on the website.

Comment: seems like a dynamic programming problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

Let's first suppose K = 1 and that S looks like (using a dot for 0):

```
..1...11...11.....111111....111....
      e    f      b  a c    d
```

The key is to note that if the longest acceptable sequence contains a `1` it will also contain any adjacent ones. For example, if the longest sequence contains the 1 at *a*, it will also contain all of the ones between *b* and *c* (inclusive).

So you only have to analyze the sequence at the points where the blocks of ones are.

The main question is: if you start at a certain block of ones, can you make it to the next block of ones? For instance, if you start at *e* you can make it to the block at *f* but not to *b*. If you start at *b* you can make it to the block at *d*, etc.

Then generalize the analysis for K > 1.

Comment: This is a good start, but not enough unfortunately. You can also compress blocks like `1*n 0*k 1*m` where `3 * min(m, n) >= 2 * k`. Obviously these blocks always go together. Finding the longest sequence by going from one block of ones to the next left to right fails for example on this sequence: `1100100010011` where the solution is the whole sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force obviously won't work since it's `O((n * k) ** 2)`. I will use python style list comprehensions in this answer. You'll need an array `t = [3 if el == "1" else - 2 for el in S]`. Now if you use the `p[i] = t[0] + ... + t[i]` array you can see that in the `k == 1` case you are basically looking for a pair (i, j), i < j such that `p[j] -  (p[i - 1] if i != 0 else 0) >= 0` is true and `j - i` is maximal among 
these pairs. Now for each `i in 0..n-1` you have to find find it's `j` pair such that the above is maximal. This can be done in `O(log n)` for a specific `i` so this gives and `O(n log n)` solution for the k == 1 case. This can be extended to an `O(n log n)` solution for the general case(there is a trick to find the largest block that can be covered). Also there is an `O(n)` solution to this problem but you need to  further examine the `p` sequence for that. I don't suggest to write a solution in a scripting language though. Even the `O(n)` solution times out in python...